# What's the proper way to disable ajax cache on select2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-select2

I'm using select2 to load remote data to an html select

The issue with it is that if user selects an option -> clears the input -> data changes in server -> user search for the data again. If I ask for data selected it returns the old (previusly selected) values.

Example:

```
//User search for an option and selects it 
$('#someSelect').select2('data').Limit 
//Here the limit is 0 
//Server data changes on server. Now limit is 10 
//User searchs again for the same option and selects it 
$('#someSelect').select2('data').Limit 
//The value returned in the line above is 0 again 
//Somehow the data previously selected is cached 
//and returned instead of the refreshed data
```

Setting cache:false doesn't do anything.

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand your question.

Comment: Sorry me, english is not my first language so I have to struggle a little to get me understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After hours I figured out the solution.

On the event select2:unselect I had to clear all the options of the select because the plugin has added the selected option to the DOM.

```
$('#someSelect').on('select2:unselect',function(){
    $('#someSelect').html(null);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also [reset](http://www.dotnetqueries.com/Article/156/how-to-resest-jquery-select2-dropdown) the select2 dropdown to clear the options..

```
$('#someSelect').select2("val", "All");
```